# Nested JSON to Pandas DataFrame with Multiple Tags

Tags: python, json, pandas

I hope you are doing well. I have some json files and I want to convert the Json to DataFrame. I converted many of its columns but have only one problem left. [image] in the image you can see that I can get the "Venue_info" details successfully. But when I want to get the data from "analysis" its giving errors.
I want to make the seperate column of "day_text" in the analysis field.

```
df_json = pd.read_json("C:/Users/IT City/Desktop/Hantz/TripAdvisor-Sanfrancisco/BestTimeData/TripAdvisor-Delivery/1-50-TripAdvisor-Delivery-Final-File.json")
bn = pd.DataFrame(df_json.venue_info.tolist())['venue_name']
```

This code is working fine. But below is not working fine.

```
bn = pd.DataFrame(df_json.analysis.tolist())['day_int']
```

Can you please help me in this regard.

Thank you

Arslan

Below is the Sample JSON

[{"status":"OK","epoch_analysis":"1634031396","venue_info":{"venue_id":"ven_55785f7837416f3850777a5241596841475f62644e576c4a496843","venue_name":"North Beach Restaurant","venue_address":"1512 Stockton St San Francisco, CA 94133 United States","venue_timezone":"America/Los_Angeles","venue_dwell_time_min":0,"venue_dwell_time_max":0,"venue_dwell_time_avg":0,"venue_type":"ITALIAN_RESTAURANT","venue_types":["northern_italian_restaurant","italian_restaurant","tuscan_restaurant"],"venue_lat":37.7997867,"venue_lon":-122.40893829999999},"analysis":[{"day_info":{"day_int":0,"day_text":"Monday","venue_open":"Closed","venue_closed":"Closed","day_rank_mean":7,"day_rank_max":7},"busy_hours":[],"quiet_hours":[],"peak_hours":[{"peak_info":"No peaks for today"}],"surge_hours":{"most_people_come":"N/A","most_people_leave":"N/A"},"hour_analysis":[{"hour":6,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":7,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":8,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":9,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":10,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":11,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":12,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":13,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":14,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":15,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":16,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":17,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":18,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":19,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":20,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":21,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":22,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":23,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":0,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":1,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":2,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":3,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":4,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":5,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"}],"day_raw":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"day_info":{"day_int":1,"day_text":"Tuesday","venue_open":"Closed","venue_closed":"Closed","day_rank_mean":7,"day_rank_max":7},"busy_hours":[],"quiet_hours":[],"peak_hours":[{"peak_info":"No peaks for today"}],"surge_hours":{"most_people_come":"N/A","most_people_leave":"N/A"},"hour_analysis":[{"hour":6,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":7,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":8,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":9,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":10,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":11,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":12,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":13,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":14,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":15,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":16,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":17,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":18,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":19,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":20,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":21,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":22,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":23,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":0,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":1,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":2,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":3,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":4,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":5,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"}],"day_raw":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"day_info":{"day_int":2,"day_text":"Wednesday","venue_open":17,"venue_closed":21,"day_rank_mean":5,"day_rank_max":5,"day_mean":35,"day_max":38},"busy_hours":[],"quiet_hours":[17,18,19,20,21],"peak_hours":[],"surge_hours":{"most_people_come":17,"most_people_leave":20},"hour_analysis":[{"hour":6,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":7,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":8,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":9,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":10,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":11,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":12,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":13,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":14,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":15,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":16,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":17,"intensity_txt":"Below average","intensity_nr":-1},{"hour":18,"intensity_txt":"Below average","intensity_nr":-1},{"hour":19,"intensity_txt":"Below average","intensity_nr":-1},{"hour":20,"intensity_txt":"Below average","intensity_nr":-1},{"hour":21,"intensity_txt":"Low","intensity_nr":-2},{"hour":22,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":23,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":0,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":1,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":2,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":3,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":4,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":5,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"}],"day_raw":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,30,35,40,35,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"day_info":{"day_int":3,"day_text":"Thursday","venue_open":17,"venue_closed":21,"day_rank_mean":3,"day_rank_max":4,"day_mean":56,"day_max":63},"busy_hours":[],"quiet_hours":[21],"peak_hours":[],"surge_hours":{"most_people_come":17,"most_people_leave":20},"hour_analysis":[{"hour":6,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":7,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":8,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":9,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":10,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":11,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":12,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":13,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":14,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":15,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":16,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":17,"intensity_txt":"Average","intensity_nr":0},{"hour":18,"intensity_txt":"Average","intensity_nr":0},{"hour":19,"intensity_txt":"Average","intensity_nr":0},{"hour":20,"intensity_txt":"Average","intensity_nr":0},{"hour":21,"intensity_txt":"Low","intensity_nr":-2},{"hour":22,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":23,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":0,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":1,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":2,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":3,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":4,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":5,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"}],"day_raw":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,50,60,65,55,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"day_info":{"day_int":4,"day_text":"Friday","venue_open":17,"venue_closed":22,"day_rank_mean":2,"day_rank_max":2,"day_mean":72,"day_max":98},"busy_hours":[19,20],"quiet_hours":[22],"peak_hours":[{"peak_start":17,"peak_max":19,"peak_end":21,"peak_intensity":5,"peak_delta_mean_week":37}],"surge_hours":{"most_people_come":17,"most_people_leave":21},"hour_analysis":[{"hour":6,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":7,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":8,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":9,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":10,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":11,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":12,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":13,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":14,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":15,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":16,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":17,"intensity_txt":"Average","intensity_nr":0},{"hour":18,"intensity_txt":"Above average","intensity_nr":1},{"hour":19,"intensity_txt":"High","intensity_nr":2},{"hour":20,"intensity_txt":"High","intensity_nr":2},{"hour":21,"intensity_txt":"Average","intensity_nr":0},{"hour":22,"intensity_txt":"Low","intensity_nr":-2},{"hour":23,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":0,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":1,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":2,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":3,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":4,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":5,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"}],"day_raw":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,45,75,100,85,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"day_info":{"day_int":5,"day_text":"Saturday","venue_open":17,"venue_closed":22,"day_rank_mean":1,"day_rank_max":1,"day_mean":81,"day_max":100},"busy_hours":[18,19,20,21],"quiet_hours":[22],"peak_hours":[{"peak_start":17,"peak_max":19,"peak_end":21,"peak_intensity":5,"peak_delta_mean_week":39}],"surge_hours":{"most_people_come":17,"most_people_leave":21},"hour_analysis":[{"hour":6,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":7,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":8,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":9,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":10,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":11,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":12,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":13,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":14,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":15,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":16,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":17,"intensity_txt":"Average","intensity_nr":0},{"hour":18,"intensity_txt":"Above average","intensity_nr":1},{"hour":19,"intensity_txt":"High","intensity_nr":2},{"hour":20,"intensity_txt":"High","intensity_nr":2},{"hour":21,"intensity_txt":"Above average","intensity_nr":1},{"hour":22,"intensity_txt":"Low","intensity_nr":-2},{"hour":23,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":0,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":1,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":2,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":3,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":4,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":5,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"}],"day_raw":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,50,80,100,100,75,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"day_info":{"day_int":6,"day_text":"Sunday","venue_open":17,"venue_closed":21,"day_rank_mean":4,"day_rank_max":3,"day_mean":52,"day_max":73},"busy_hours":[],"quiet_hours":[17,21],"peak_hours":[],"surge_hours":{"most_people_come":18,"most_people_leave":20},"hour_analysis":[{"hour":6,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":7,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":8,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":9,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":10,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":11,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":12,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":13,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":14,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":15,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":16,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":17,"intensity_txt":"Below average","intensity_nr":-1},{"hour":18,"intensity_txt":"Below average","intensity_nr":-1},{"hour":19,"intensity_txt":"Average","intensity_nr":0},{"hour":20,"intensity_txt":"Average","intensity_nr":0},{"hour":21,"intensity_txt":"Low","intensity_nr":-2},{"hour":22,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":23,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":0,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":1,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":2,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":3,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":4,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":5,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"}],"day_raw":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25,45,75,65,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}],"api_key_private":"pri_d4471a5e8ae647fda9505d5c5d0427d4"}]

Answer (score 1):

Utilize `pandas`' `.json_normalize()`

```
import pandas as pd

df_json = [{"status":"OK","epoch_analysis":"1634031396","venue_info":{"venue_id":"ven_55785f7837416f3850777a5241596841475f62644e576c4a496843","venue_name":"North Beach Restaurant","venue_address":"1512 Stockton St San Francisco, CA 94133 United States","venue_timezone":"America/Los_Angeles","venue_dwell_time_min":0,"venue_dwell_time_max":0,"venue_dwell_time_avg":0,"venue_type":"ITALIAN_RESTAURANT","venue_types":["northern_italian_restaurant","italian_restaurant","tuscan_restaurant"],"venue_lat":37.7997867,"venue_lon":-122.40893829999999},"analysis":[{"day_info":{"day_int":0,"day_text":"Monday","venue_open":"Closed","venue_closed":"Closed","day_rank_mean":7,"day_rank_max":7},"busy_hours":[],"quiet_hours":[],"peak_hours":[{"peak_info":"No peaks for today"}],"surge_hours":{"most_people_come":"N/A","most_people_leave":"N/A"},"hour_analysis":[{"hour":6,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":7,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":8,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":9,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":10,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":11,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":12,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":13,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":14,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":15,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":16,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":17,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":18,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":19,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":20,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":21,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":22,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":23,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":0,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":1,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":2,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":3,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":4,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":5,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"}],"day_raw":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"day_info":{"day_int":1,"day_text":"Tuesday","venue_open":"Closed","venue_closed":"Closed","day_rank_mean":7,"day_rank_max":7},"busy_hours":[],"quiet_hours":[],"peak_hours":[{"peak_info":"No peaks for today"}],"surge_hours":{"most_people_come":"N/A","most_people_leave":"N/A"},"hour_analysis":[{"hour":6,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":7,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":8,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":9,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":10,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":11,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":12,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":13,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":14,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":15,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":16,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":17,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":18,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":19,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":20,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":21,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":22,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":23,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":0,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":1,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":2,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":3,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":4,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"},{"hour":5,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"N/A"}],"day_raw":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"day_info":{"day_int":2,"day_text":"Wednesday","venue_open":17,"venue_closed":21,"day_rank_mean":5,"day_rank_max":5,"day_mean":35,"day_max":38},"busy_hours":[],"quiet_hours":[17,18,19,20,21],"peak_hours":[],"surge_hours":{"most_people_come":17,"most_people_leave":20},"hour_analysis":[{"hour":6,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":7,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":8,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":9,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":10,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":11,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":12,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":13,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":14,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":15,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":16,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":17,"intensity_txt":"Below average","intensity_nr":-1},{"hour":18,"intensity_txt":"Below average","intensity_nr":-1},{"hour":19,"intensity_txt":"Below average","intensity_nr":-1},{"hour":20,"intensity_txt":"Below average","intensity_nr":-1},{"hour":21,"intensity_txt":"Low","intensity_nr":-2},{"hour":22,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":23,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":0,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":1,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":2,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":3,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":4,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":5,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"}],"day_raw":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,30,35,40,35,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"day_info":{"day_int":3,"day_text":"Thursday","venue_open":17,"venue_closed":21,"day_rank_mean":3,"day_rank_max":4,"day_mean":56,"day_max":63},"busy_hours":[],"quiet_hours":[21],"peak_hours":[],"surge_hours":{"most_people_come":17,"most_people_leave":20},"hour_analysis":[{"hour":6,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":7,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":8,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":9,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":10,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":11,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":12,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":13,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":14,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":15,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":16,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":17,"intensity_txt":"Average","intensity_nr":0},{"hour":18,"intensity_txt":"Average","intensity_nr":0},{"hour":19,"intensity_txt":"Average","intensity_nr":0},{"hour":20,"intensity_txt":"Average","intensity_nr":0},{"hour":21,"intensity_txt":"Low","intensity_nr":-2},{"hour":22,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":23,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":0,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":1,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":2,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":3,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":4,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":5,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"}],"day_raw":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,50,60,65,55,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"day_info":{"day_int":4,"day_text":"Friday","venue_open":17,"venue_closed":22,"day_rank_mean":2,"day_rank_max":2,"day_mean":72,"day_max":98},"busy_hours":[19,20],"quiet_hours":[22],"peak_hours":[{"peak_start":17,"peak_max":19,"peak_end":21,"peak_intensity":5,"peak_delta_mean_week":37}],"surge_hours":{"most_people_come":17,"most_people_leave":21},"hour_analysis":[{"hour":6,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":7,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":8,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":9,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":10,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":11,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":12,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":13,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":14,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":15,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":16,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":17,"intensity_txt":"Average","intensity_nr":0},{"hour":18,"intensity_txt":"Above average","intensity_nr":1},{"hour":19,"intensity_txt":"High","intensity_nr":2},{"hour":20,"intensity_txt":"High","intensity_nr":2},{"hour":21,"intensity_txt":"Average","intensity_nr":0},{"hour":22,"intensity_txt":"Low","intensity_nr":-2},{"hour":23,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":0,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":1,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":2,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":3,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":4,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":5,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"}],"day_raw":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,45,75,100,85,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"day_info":{"day_int":5,"day_text":"Saturday","venue_open":17,"venue_closed":22,"day_rank_mean":1,"day_rank_max":1,"day_mean":81,"day_max":100},"busy_hours":[18,19,20,21],"quiet_hours":[22],"peak_hours":[{"peak_start":17,"peak_max":19,"peak_end":21,"peak_intensity":5,"peak_delta_mean_week":39}],"surge_hours":{"most_people_come":17,"most_people_leave":21},"hour_analysis":[{"hour":6,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":7,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":8,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":9,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":10,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":11,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":12,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":13,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":14,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":15,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":16,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":17,"intensity_txt":"Average","intensity_nr":0},{"hour":18,"intensity_txt":"Above average","intensity_nr":1},{"hour":19,"intensity_txt":"High","intensity_nr":2},{"hour":20,"intensity_txt":"High","intensity_nr":2},{"hour":21,"intensity_txt":"Above average","intensity_nr":1},{"hour":22,"intensity_txt":"Low","intensity_nr":-2},{"hour":23,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":0,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":1,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":2,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":3,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":4,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":5,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"}],"day_raw":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,50,80,100,100,75,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"day_info":{"day_int":6,"day_text":"Sunday","venue_open":17,"venue_closed":21,"day_rank_mean":4,"day_rank_max":3,"day_mean":52,"day_max":73},"busy_hours":[],"quiet_hours":[17,21],"peak_hours":[],"surge_hours":{"most_people_come":18,"most_people_leave":20},"hour_analysis":[{"hour":6,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":7,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":8,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":9,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":10,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":11,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":12,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":13,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":14,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":15,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":16,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":17,"intensity_txt":"Below average","intensity_nr":-1},{"hour":18,"intensity_txt":"Below average","intensity_nr":-1},{"hour":19,"intensity_txt":"Average","intensity_nr":0},{"hour":20,"intensity_txt":"Average","intensity_nr":0},{"hour":21,"intensity_txt":"Low","intensity_nr":-2},{"hour":22,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":23,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":0,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":1,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":2,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":3,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":4,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"},{"hour":5,"intensity_txt":"Closed","intensity_nr":"999"}],"day_raw":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25,45,75,65,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}],"api_key_private":"pri_d4471a5e8ae647fda9505d5c5d0427d4"}]
    

bn1 = pd.json_normalize(df_json)['venue_info.venue_name']
bn2 = pd.json_normalize(df_json, record_path=['analysis'])['day_info.day_int']
```

**Output:**

```
print(bn1)
0    North Beach Restaurant
Name: venue_info.venue_name, dtype: object


print(bn2)
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
Name: day_info.day_int, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you chitown88. Its really helpful.